# Simple Scrolling Text Without Using Scroller Help - AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

on a stage I have a textfield, my goal is to be able to scroll through the textfield without using UIScroller, I want to scroll the textfield by only dragging the mouse up or down. It doesn't work...

```
textfield.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_MouseClickHandler);
function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    textfield.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, fl_MouseClickHandler3);
}

function fl_MouseClickHandler3(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(stage.mouseY+1){ //when the cursorY goes down the text goes down too
        textfield.scrollV++;
    }

    if(stage.mouseY-1){ //when the cursorY goes up the text goes up too
        textfield.scrollV--;
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't working because your `if` conditions are not checking for the proper information.  I would compare the cursor position in relation to the textfield.  So for argument's sake, if the cursor is below the vertical half-way point of the textfield, scroll down, and if it's above, scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

I got this code working however, you have other issues you need to also address:

1. When a user drags outside of the TextField object, and then hovers over the TextField again, the handler fires again because the mouse move listener was never removed.
2. The amount of scrolling to apply needs to be fine tuned to properly account for the amount of text in the TextField.  I did not adjust this because I did not want to implement something that was outside of your design requirements.

Try this code:

```
textfield.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    textfield.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, fl_MouseClickHandler3);
}

function fl_MouseClickHandler3(e:MouseEvent):void
{

    if( stage.mouseY > e.target.y + e.target.height / 2){ //when the cursorY goes down the text goes down too
        textfield.scrollV++;
    } else {
        textfield.scrollV--;
    }

}
```